# Why the form return 'Method not allowed' while extending CreateView CBV in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am not sure what is not working correctly here. The CBV CreateView include a form but when I try to click on 'submit' in the template I receive the 'error' `Method Not Allowed (POST)`

forms.py

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('check_in', 
                'check_out')
        widgets = {
            'check_in': DateInput(),
            'check_out': DateInput()
        }
```

```
class PropertyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = PropertyListing
    context_object_name = 'name'
    template_name = 'core/property-detail.html'


    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PropertyDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['property_details'] = PropertyListing.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        # Form
        context['form'] = BookingForm()
        return context
```

just the form
HTML

```
 <form class="col-sm-3" role="form" action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create" />
 </form>
```

Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: A `DetailView` typically does not accept POST calls. You can implement `def post(..)`, but likely it is better to use a `FormMixin`

Comment: This has tons of duplicates.

Comment: Note that contrary to the title, you are *not* extending CreateView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) does not implement a handler for POST requests. Therefore if you make a POST request to the handler, it will produce a HTTP 405 error: Method not allowed.

We thus will need to implement a handler for a POST request ourselves. The good news is that a lot of functionality is already implemented in the [**`ModelFormMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin). We thus can implement this like:

```
class PropertyDetailView(ModelFormMixin, DetailView):
    model = PropertyListing
    context_object_name = 'name'
    template_name = 'core/property-detail.html'
    form_class = BookingForm
    success_url = ...

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PropertyDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['property_details'] = PropertyListing.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return context

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

You thus do not need to add a `Form` to the context data (the `ModelFormMixin` will do that), nor do you need to handle the form yourself. You will however need to specify a [**`success_url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url), or override the [**`form_valid`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid).

That being said, it might be better to use a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) or an [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView), and just apply some code changes to add details of your objects to it.